# How can I call on a DataGrid's "selected item" from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Below I have a method for deleting a record from a database. It works great while it is on the same dialog. The problem is that I want to have this method on another window, a form dialog, not a DataGrid. Once I move it, it no longer works.

```
    public partial class ProjectsTable : Window
{
    public ProjectsTable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //populates a DataGrid called "ProjectData" on the "ProjectsTable.xaml"
    private void Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BillableProjectsDataContext project = new BillableProjectsDataContext();
        List<Project> projects = (from p in project.Projects
                                  select p).ToList();
        ProjectData.ItemsSource = projects;
    }

    // deletes the selected project
    private void btnDeleteProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this is the most important part, it tells the method which record to delete
        Project selected = ProjectData.SelectedItem as Project;
        //calls another class called "Menu_SQL" and uses it's DeleteProject method
        Menu_SQL.DeleteProject(selected);
        Window_Loaded(null, null);
    }
}
```

the above method works just fine, the problem is that I want to have this method on my form, which is another window
once I move it, it no longer works.

The specific error is "The name 'ProjectData' does not exist in the current context".

But it does exist, it is the name of the DataGrid.

```
public partial class DataForm : Window
{
    public Project project;
    public DataForm(Project project)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.project = project;
    }
    public DataForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // deletes the selected project, the same exact method as before, just in another window
    private void btnDeleteProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this is the most important part, it tells the method which record to delete
        // the problem is that this line will error because "The name 'ProjectData' does not exist in the current context"
        Project selected = ProjectData.SelectedItem as Project;
        Menu_SQL.DeleteProject(selected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a property in DataForm like

`public DataGrid ProjectData { set; get; }`

You can set it before DataForm show.